# Hide the dock programmatically on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, cocoa, osx-snow-leopard, macos-carbon

I am working on a new software for Mac OS X Snow Leopard, and one of the features I need to implement is when my application starts, hide the Dock completely and block Spotlight from working while the application is running. Anyone knows if this is possible and how to do it?

Comment: I'm a little scared where you're going here.  Looking at your past questions it sounds like you're trying to run a process from the browser, which will disable the dock and disable spotlight so you can't get any apps to run.  You're also trying to intercept key combinations so the smart users can't force quit your application or use a launcher of some sort.  Don't be evil...

Comment: relax man, you are a bit paranoic :D remember a knife could be a useful tool or a dangerous weapon but is the use of that what makes the diference. dont panic !!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree with comment - "don't be evil".

And considering you won't be evil, [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/KioskMode/Introduction/Introduction.html) can be your solution.

Comment: Hmm, I didn't know about that.  I'll delete my answer then. ;)

Comment: thanks Raul, I wont be evil the aproach of the post you did is exactly what i mean a kiosk mode to let the user another kind of experience. :D thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

[try this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5327/is-it-possible-to-hide-the-dock-on-a-per-application-basis), not sure about spotlight, but this has the dock and menu bar hiding.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! Link-only answers are generally not welcomed. Please expand your answer with important highlights from the link.

Answer (score 0):

Use OS X **Kiosk Mode**

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/KioskMode/Introduction/Introduction.html

Use the bitmask `NSApplicationPresentationOptions` to enable the Kiosk Mode options you would like to use.

For your specific request, *"hide the Dock completely and block Spotlight from working while the application is running."*

`NSApplicationPresentationHideDock`

> Dock is entirely unavailable. Spotlight menu is disabled.

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
     @try {
          NSApplicationPresentationOptions options = NSApplicationPresentationHideDock;
          [NSApp setPresentationOptions:options];
     }
     @catch(NSException * exception) {
          NSLog(@"Error. Make sure you have a valid combination of options.");
     }
}
```